# colorbox border images wont load

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am working with jquery and colorbox

here are my script tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="js/libs/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

also using the `colorbox.css` style sheet as well.

My question is that the colorbox border images that come along with the examples are not loading when I test my site in a browser. All of colorbox's functionalities work correct; but the images i copied into my images folder from the colorbox examples will not load. When i look at the console in Chrome i get these messages:

```
Failed to load resource: website/css/images/border1.png

Failed to load resource: website/css/images/border2.png
```

but all my other images are still showing up just fine.

Why is this happening??

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: check if your specified directories are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you relocated the images without letting the ColorBox plugin know. Or you didn't actually move the images to the locations ColorBox expects them.

Inspect the plugin's CSS file carefully. By default, ColorBox expects the images it needs (not your images) to be in the folder images which is a subdirectory of the directory that stores the CSS file.

Comment: yep thanks this worked perfectly! i had to change the directory to `../css` for it to work haha